# Magento delete SKU from order email

Tags: magento

In my new order email I have SKU of product, but I want delete it from order email. How can I do this?

Comment: It isnt there, I saw it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is actually a good question. Thanks for asking Patrik.

This operation can't be done from admin interface as the block with order items is inserted into the template. If you will take a look into `app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html` you will see the following code which will be replaces with ordered items block during rendering:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

As you can see the handle of the block is `sales_email_order_items` and it's declaration can be found in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml`. Here it is:

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_items>
```

Here you will see two templates mentioned `/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/items.phtml` and `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml`. Copy them into your theme and modify them.

The first one keeps the heading of the table with items. You will have to remove line 37:

```
<th><?php echo $this->__('SKU') ?></th>
```

The second one renders the row of the table body. There you have to remove line 64:

```
<td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape(Mage::helper('core/string')->splitInjection($this->getSku())) ?></td>
```

You don't need to copy layout xml to your theme. Just those 2 template files.

Unfortunately it will also remove SKU column from orders view in customers account as these templates are used there also. So if you want to remove SKU column from email only you will have to create a new handle in `local.xml` file of your theme identical to one present in `sales.xml`. Then you will have to create customized copy of your email template at Magento admin and put your new handle into `{{layout}}` shortcode. Of course both templates will also need to be duplicated with different names.

Comment: You can prevent the customer's account section from being affected by changing the layout handle in the email template to your own custom handle that calls your own template instead, leaving the original intact for any other areas that need it.